# Unable to get CakePHP's REST to work with Backbone (or at all)

Tags: cakephp, rest, backbone.js

I am trying to get a backbone-based front end to work with my CakePHP application.

I have the following in *routes.php* (along with some other routes)

```
Router::mapResources(array('rooms', 'comments'));
Router::parseExtensions();
```

Now using things like `GET /rooms/XX.json` works fine, so far so good. I am trying to use Backbone to delete a comment, however. In my application bootstrap I have the following:

```
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
```

Because I know PHP doesn't play too nicely with REST. Thus `X-HTTP-Method-Override` is set to `DELETE` on request. Despite me then requesting `POST /comments/160.json` with `X-HTTP-Method-Override DELETE` I get the following response:

```
{
    "code":"404",
    "url":"\/comments\/160.json","name":"Action CommentsController::view() could not be found."
}
```

**CommentsController::view() could not be found**

I cannot, for the life of me, get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using `Router::mapResources(array(...));` was not working. It would work for the first controller but not the second. Thus I have changed my *routes.php* file to use:

```
...
Router::mapResources('rooms');
Router::mapResources('comments');
...
```

It seems to now be working, which is odd, because looking at the [CakePHP source code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Routing/Router.php#L476) it should cycle through all of them.